# use SessionLogoutHandler to add data in database

Tags: symfony

i have a symfony application where a logout () is not manually :

> ( in file routing.yml)

```
logout:
pattern:   /logout
```

and i would like when i click on **/logout** we must be able to record information in the database  and for that i use :

```
SessionLogoutHandler class
```

here is my code :

```
namespace Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Logout;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

use Compta\MyappliBundle\Entity\LogTache;
use Compta\MyappliBundle\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
class SessionLogoutHandler implements LogoutHandlerInterface
{
    public function logout(Request $request, Response $response, TokenInterface $token)
    {

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
            $user= $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
            $u = new LogTache();

            $u->setDate(new \DateTime());
            $u->setUser($user->getUsername());
            $u->setActioneffectue('Déconnexion');

            $em->flush($u);

    $request->getSession()->invalidate();

    } }
```

when i click on **/logout** i get an error :

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Logout\SessionLogoutHandler::getDoctrine()
>   in
>   C:\wamp\www\MyAppli\vendor\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Logout\SessionLogoutHandler.php
>   on line 46

how to solve it ? 
thank in advance

excuse my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have access to the container from that class. The `$this->getDoctrine()...` and `$this->get()` is more likely to be found in a controller action.

You can add a constructor and pass in '@doctrine' and '@security.context' as arguments from the service definition, or with Symfony 3.3 type-hint the appropriate classes (for Doctrine - `Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager`) and use them within the class.

Symfony 2.6 deprecated the security.context service, so it's also quote likely you are running a older version of the framework. Upgrading may bring additional benefits, such as the v3.3+ auto-wiring of services.